# Для чего нужен RETURN во вложенном блоке процедуры?

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

Что вернёт в процедуре RETURN, если условие будет верно?

```
PROCEDURE reload(p_sequence VARCHAR2) IS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        lb_is_enabled CHAR (1);
    BEGIN
        BEGIN
            SELECT is_enabled INTO lb_is_enabled
            FROM tload
            WHERE sequence_name = p_sequence;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;
        END;

        IF NVL (lb_is_enabled, 'Y') != 'Y'
        THEN
            RETURN;
        END IF;
    END;
END;
```

Или данная конструкция нужна, чтобы просто выйти из вложенного блока?

Comment: из какого цикла?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае, [RETURN](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/RETURN-statement.html#GUID-2DCDD1F2-041A-479C-A2F8-B3B68F50FE5D) немедленно прекратит выполнение процедуры, включая все блоки `BEGIN ... END;`, к которым он относится.

> The RETURN statement immediately ends the execution of the subprogram or anonymous block that contains it.

Так как процедуры ничего не возвращают, и независимо от результата:

```
IF <условие> THEN
    RETURN;
END IF;
```

процедура закончится, то этот фрагмент кода бессмыслен и может быть удалён.

Comment: Спасибо большое за объяснение.